# Select single id from NULL

Tags: select, null

We are having a database full with set ID's. To fill the database, we have to select one single ID every time. This may only be an ID where the rest of the values are set with NULL (empty).
How to do this?

```
SELECT `id` FROM `ids` WHERE `datetime` IS NULL
```

returns all empty ID's. I just have to select one of them at random.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use TOP 1 and order by newid() to get a random row returned. As in:

`SELECT TOP 1 id FROM ids WHERE datetime IS NULL ORDER by newid()`

Answer (score 1):

As you yourself suggested, use `LIMIT 1` to select the top result. This is not very random, but if it suits your needs, its fine.